# How to figure out test environment in android programmatically

Tags: android

I am working with multiple content providers in my application. All of these content providers talk to a singleton instance of SQliteOpenHelper (which works with application context). This works great in production. When it comes to testing (Content provider testing specifically), having a singleton instance of SQLiteOpenHelper is not good idea as it does not create clean slate database for every test run

In content provider code, I want to figure whether I am in a test mode or not, depending on that I will decide to switch between a singleton open hleper or per context open helper

Are there any good ways to do it..does android provide any api to determine if the app is in test mode ?

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure if this is what you want, but there is a method getApplicationContext() in the Context class. Try this and see if it solves your problem.

Comment: getApplicationContext throws UnSupportedOperationException in testing environment...my test case extends [ProviderTestCase2](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/test/ProviderTestCase2.html)